# modifying json with jsonbuilder in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I am trying to modify content of json and then print it to see if it has changed with this code but getting error

```
 def builder = new JsonBuilder(request)
 log.info(builder.content)
 builder.content.device.dpidsha1= 'abcd'  
 log.info(builder.toPrettyString())
```

error:

```
no such property: device
```

json looks like this:

```
{
   "app":{ },
   "at":2,
   "badv":[ ],
   "bcat":[ ],
   "device":{
      "carrier":"310-410",
      "connectiontype":3,
      "devicetype":1,
      "dnt":0,
      "dpidmd5":"268d403db34e32c45869bb1401247af9",
      "dpidsha1":"1234",
.
.
}
```

can someone help in understanding what am i doing wrong and how can i correct it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to parse incoming data, then modify it with `JsonBuilder`

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def data = """
{
   "app":{ },
   "at":2,
   "badv":[ ],
   "bcat":[ ],
   "device":{
      "carrier":"310-410",
      "connectiontype":3,
      "devicetype":1,
      "dnt":0,
      "dpidmd5":"268d403db34e32c45869bb1401247af9",
      "dpidsha1":"1234" 
   }
}"""

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(data)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped)
builder.content.device.dpidsha1 = 'abcd'  
println(builder.toPrettyString())
```

Comment: Thanks! Whatever that means :)

Comment: @Opal: I didn't know about `toPrettyString()` before :)

Comment: Ah... you're right - so I'll vote up the question too ;)

Comment: Corrected @mmigdol. Thanks! Not sure if groovy's parser behavior is correct here. It should fail with such errors :/

Comment: Unfortunately it fails to parse this JSON without curly brace in groovy 2.1.6 but works perfectly fine in 2.3.6 :/

Comment: Yes I know that. It works in such a way after introducing Boon parser.

Comment: @Opal Thank You.  its printing json with changed value. I noticed in printed json that it has rearranged a lot of values. Not sure why, doesnt seem like alphabatically. But it should work(my server not responding right now). Is there a way to print the same way as original request with changed value?

Comment: Bo idea how to do it. I suppose the order may be random.

Comment: Excellent so `.content` is the key here to modify this json.

Comment: Thanks. So the var `content` has nothing to do with the `builder.content`, correct?

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam `builder.content` refers to [this](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html#getContent()) method - correct, it has nothing to do with var `content`.

Comment: Thanks @Opal for the clarification.

Comment: I think the variable in the example should be named differently for clarification (e.g. `def data = """...`). I tripped over the name shadowing as well.