# How to read and ouput Json file with groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I am trying to: 1. read a json file with groovy; 2. change the object a little bit; 3. output/override as a new json file.

so far, I know we can use `import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;`, but I searched some samples, all for parse the `.txt` file (convert txt to json format object) like this:

```
def inputFile = file('json_input/' + fileName)
def inputJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
print out...
```

but not read json file directly.

Is there any simple way to read and get the json object from a `.json` file so that I can make some changes of the data?

Thanks!

Comment: file extentation doesn't matter. You can read json from `.txt` file, `.json`  and even from a `.foo` file  as long as its a valid json

Comment: take a look at this answer.  the easy way is to parse into the builder http://stackoverflow.com/a/25748859/3181392