# How to substitute parameter value in a json file using Groovy

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is there any simple way to replace the version from "**1.0.2**" to "**2.6.5**" in a json file "**deploy.json**" using groovy scripting , and the file content has been provided below.

```
{
  "versions": [
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "replian"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "hp"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "shutoff"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "spark"
        }
            ]
}
```

I tried the below, but getting an error;

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def content = """
{
  "versions": [
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "replian"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "hp"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "shutoff"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "spark"
        }
            ]
}"""

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped) 
builder.content.versions.find{it.version}.version = "2.6.5"
println(builder.toPrettyString())
```

**ISSUE:**
Only first conf version is replaced 
e.g.
    {
        "version": "2.6.5",
        "conf": "replian"
    },
    {
        "version": "1.0.2",
        "conf": "hp"
    },
    {
        "version": "1.0.2",
        "conf": "shutoff"
    },
    {
        "version": "1.0.2",
        "conf": "spark"
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [modifying json with jsonbuilder in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748170/modifying-json-with-jsonbuilder-in-groovy)

Answer (score 1):

Using `jq`:

```
$ jq '.versions[].version="2.6.5"' deploy.json
{
  "app": "Beach",
  "Process": "steam",
  "versions": [
    {
      "version": "2.6.5",
      "conf": "replian"
    }, ...
```

Or awk, if you must:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="([^:]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    OFS=":"
}
$1~"\"version\"" {
    sub(/"[^"]*"/,"\"2.6.5\"",$2)
}1' deploy.json
```

Some output:

```
{
  "app": "Beach",
  "Process": "steam",
  "versions": [
        {
            "version": "2.6.5",
            "conf": "replian"
        }, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to suggest `groovy` to do this.

**Edited :** See the `// Edited Line`

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def content = """
{
  "app": "Beach",
  "Process": "steam",
  "versions": [
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "replian"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "hp"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "shutoff"
        },
        {
            "version": "1.0.2",
            "conf": "spark"
        }
            ]
}"""

def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(content)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(slurped) 
builder.content.versions.find{it.version}.version = "2.6.5" // Edited Line
println(builder.toPrettyString())

// Updated Line
new File ("out.json").text = builder.toPrettyString()
```

Comment: groovy.json.JsonException: expecting a ',' or a ']',  but got 
the current character of  ':' with an int value of 58  on array index of 16 


The current character read is ':' with an int value of 58
expecting a ',' or a ']',  but got 
the current character of  ':' with an int value of 58  on array index of 16 

line number 67
index number 1524
         "version": "0.0.0",
..................^
 at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.complain(JsonParserCharArray.java:153)

Comment: @itgeek Oops...! My mistake. Now i 've updated my code

Comment: Thanks Bhanu, The value replaced first config "replian", and failed to replace version in other config

Comment: @itgeek glad it helped

Comment: I want to write them to a json file after substituting the values. Can I use the below one to write the parsed data to a json file and print the file content.  
                                                                                                                     
           writeFile file: 'outputfile.json', text: content
                                                                                                    
           println('Printing the output json file: ' + outputfile.json)

Comment: @itgeek if you want in output you can add a new line as i 've updated in the last line of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If ever you're interrested in a solution with sed : `sed 's/"version": "1\.0\.2"/"version": "2.6.5"/ deploy.json`